# Javascript 'If' to see if a form field has a number in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have some javascript in a Mongoose Schema to auto-increment a value if there's no number entered manually in the form field.

```
// before validation starts, the number of Items is counted..afterwards, the position is set

    ItemSchema.pre("validate", function(next) {

        var doc = this;

        // if 'position' is not filled in, fill it in..not using !position because 0 might be a valid value
        if(typeof position !== "number") {
            // count the number of Items *
            // use mongoose.model to fetch the model because the model is not compiled yet
            mongoose.model("Item").count(function(err, num) {
                // if there was an error, pass it to next()
                if(err)
                    return next(err);

                // set the position, then call next();
                doc.position = num;
                return next();
            });
        } else if(this.isModified("position") || this.isNew()) {
            // code to check if there is an existing document with the same position 
            // code to check move down other document positions, if existing
```

Auto-incrementing is working perfectly, but it does this regardless of whether there's a number in the field. What's a better 'if statement' to pass?

I have this form-field on the frontend:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="Position" ng-model="formData.position">
```

And I know that the data is passing through via

```
position : req.body.position,
```

because `console.log(req.body.position);` does log the number

Comment: It's not clear how/when your code is executed and how everything is related to each  other. It's difficult to help without having a clear picture of what your code does.

Comment: IF `position` is filled from an HTML element, it will be a *string value*.  There are a number of posts here on Stack Overflow about checking to see if a value is a number.

Comment: I'm guessing `position` is the value, and that's always a string, so checking the typeof fails miserably. You want `isNaN`

Comment: position is defined in a Mongoose model as a number, though does that not make a difference? `position: Number,`

Comment: @FelixKling added context for code clarity.. is this more helpful?

Comment: Why isn't it `doc.position` in your check? It's using a global variable in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// if 'position' is not filled in, fill it in
// not using !position because 0 might be a valid value
if( (parseFloat(position) || -1) == -1) {
// code for auto-incrementing
```

*parseFloat()*  will return either a *null* or *NaN* depending on the age of your browser.  The 'or' function will return the the secondary (in this case -1) in the event an error value (NaN, undefined) or null is passed.  You can change to change the -1 value to anything you want.  I just like numbers because they take up a few less bytes of memory then strings and are faster to process.

Comment: this returns a ReferenceError: position is not defined in the console, and a 500 internal server error on the browser network.. thanks though